# How can I fix dpkg after my system ran out of space?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, dpkg, disk-usage

I was installing LibreOffice on my Ubuntu phone when it ran out of space (`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`). When I attempt to purge what was installed of LibreOffice (`sudo apt-get purge libreoffice`), I am presented with the message

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I am presented with the following error:

```
dpkg: error: failed to write status database record about 'iputils-ping' to '/var/lib/dpkg/status': No space left on device
```

How should I proceed? I am trying to purge LibreOffice precisely to address this lack of space. Are there some LibreOffice package/system files I can remove manually to make enough space for the `dpkg` purge to actually run?

Comment: @George No, this is a question about getting dpkg working after it encounters low drive space, not specifically about LibreOffice.

Comment: I offered that link so you could completely remove _libreoffice_ based on the post as it seemed removing _libreoffice_ would help create more space. Basically removing less important apps would be the best option,

Comment: @George Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the *action of removing applications* cannot be done due to lack of space. So, it is not as simple as suggesting that other applications be removed *because they cannot be removed*. The best idea I've got currently is to try something like `rm -rf /var/lib/libreoffice` and to hope that `dpkg` can fix things afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I have face this out of space issues several times. This is how i solve it. Usually apt-get create some cache which holds some space on the computer. So I clean the cache, then I get some space back for the system to use to run other other process. This is the reason I don't regularly clean cache. So this is my trick

`$ sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get autoclean`

You can then purge libreoffice afterwards.

PS: When you are faced with space issue you can try clean out old kernels as well with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y`